# Front-end application with yarn starting locally but when docker container is run ports are empty

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile, yarn-v2

The port loads and I can view the app locally on port 3000. I can do this by running `yarn` the `yarn start`. The container runs and says it can be

Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:3000
http://172.17.0.2:3000

When loading the ports in my browser I see nothing. This is error is occurring with two projects I am working on.

For reference these are the front-ends I am trying to place in images.

https://github.com/Uniswap/interface/

https://github.com/safe-global/web-core

I am running node v18.12.1

The DockerFile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat git python3 py3-pip make g++
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# install deps
RUN yarn 

ENV NODE_ENV production

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

I am able to get the images to say they compiled all the code and run locally. I was expected these apps then to load on port 3000 like they do when I run it locally but this only results in an error in the browser stating "this site can't be reached"

Answer (score 0):

Port 3000 its port inside container. You have to expose port.

For example:

-p 3000:80

And open outside port 80.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: ```[eval]:1
3000:80
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at new Script (node:vm:100:7)
    at createScript (node:vm:265:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (node:vm:313:10)
    at node:internal/process/execution:79:19
    at [eval]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (node:internal/process/execution:78:60)
    at node:internal/main/eval_string:27:3```

Comment: that is the command i ran docker run gnosis -p 3000:80

Comment: docker run -p 3000:80 gnosis

Comment: This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: https://willcodeforcoffee.com/docker/2017/12/13/err_empty_response-connecting-to-a-docker-container-in-chrome.html#:~:text=ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE%20connecting%20to%20a%20Docker%20container%20in%20Chrome,-Dec%2013%2C%202017&text=When%20you%20get%20this%20error,0.1.

Comment: that isn't working either cleared cache and everything